# Python3: convert big int to float - wrong result - how do it right?

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, int

I need to do some division on a very big int in python3 *(Version 3.6.7)*. Since I always got wrong results after the division (checked with small numbers), I figured out that it is the conversion between int and float.

Why does `int(float(number))` give back another number than given in the first place?

**Number e.g.**

```
11112156454654632123512435326901347901387409791345202341234653563776467245234565435637654768245987098709846554513216562452354654823453456581
```

**After `int(float(number)` I get**

```
11112156454654632053401792328854929027579441319469717890945725999319869381390969666824878190611577646608244392592697365262211066608985571328
```

Thanks,

Really stuck at the moment.

Johannes

Comment: Floating point numbers in Python have about 16 decimal digits of precision.  See [Floating point in modern computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers).

Answer (score 0):

This is tipical of binary floating-point arithmetic. [Python doc just here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

You should take a look about **Decimal** module in your case.

```
from decimal import *
int(Decimal('11112156454654632123512435326901347901387409791345202341234653563776467245234565435637654768245987098709846554513216562452354654823453456581'))
```